# How Can I Get False in Auth::attempts Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I Have AuthController, with this code

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email:dns',
    'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials['password'] = hashPass($request['email'], $request['password']);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard')->with('loginSuccess', 'Login Berhasil');
    }

    return back()->with('loginError', 'Login Gagal!');
}
```

and i Hash with my Own Hash,
and when i dump the `$credentials`, the value is correct.

but when i dump `Auth::attempt($credentials)` i got `false` result.

Comment: Why are you hashing with your own hash if I may ask? `Auth::attempt` expects a username and password. It fetches the user record by the username and checks if the stored password hash matches the one way hash of password.

Comment: What hash driver do you have configured for your application? What is `hashPass` doing?

Comment: i use my own hash, cause i wanna try my own hash function,
and it should be same, 
`password` field in database have same value with my own hash when i check.
i use `sha1` and `md5`, just combine thats, and some string.

Comment: You're going to have to create your own Auth functions, then. `Auth::attempt` expects the plaintext password to check against the hash itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your own hash function for authentication isn't as straight forward as implementing a custom hash function and dropping it in place.

The entire process is more involved.

First, you need to create a Hasher class that implements [Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher interface](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3e8f7fa0c40a2802298ebb64c6485a413d2eccfb/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Hashing/Hasher.php).

```php
namespace App\Hashing;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher;
use RuntimeException;

class CustomHasher extends AbstractHasher implements HasherContract 
{
    public function make($value, array $options = []); {
        // perform custom routine.
    }

    /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = []) {
        // perform custom routine.
    };

    /**
     * Check if the given hash has been hashed using the given options.
     *
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = []) {
        // perform custom routine.
    };
}
```

Then implement a custom `HashManager` that includes a factory for the `CustomHash` driver.

```php
namespace App\Hashing;

use Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager;

class CustomHashManager extends HashManager
{
    /**
     * Create an instance of the Custom hash Driver.
     *
     * @return \App\Hashing\CustomHasher
     */
    public function createCustomDriver()
    {
        return new CustomHasher($this->config->get('hashing.custom') ?? []);
    }
}
```

Then implement a `ServiceProvider` to use your custom `HashManager` for driving custom hashing functionality.

```php
namespace App\Hashing;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Hashing\HashingManager;

class CustomHashServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function ($app) {
            return new CustomHashManager($app);
        });

        $this->app->singleton('hash.driver', function ($app) {
            return $app['hash']->driver();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return ['hash', 'hash.driver'];
    }
}
```

Then register `App\Hashing\CustomHashServiceProvider::class` in place of `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php`

Finally in `config/hashing.php`, configure your application to use the custom driver.

```
    'driver' => 'custom',
```

Comment: Thanks Fyi @Oluwafemi,
i got my solution for my own problem from your flow, thanks a lot